# How to download a file using web URL in python? Download through browser works but not through python's requests

Tags: python, python-requests

The file gets downloaded if the URL is entered in a browser (Firefox, Chrome, etc.). But when I tried to download the same file (using the same URL) with python's *requests* or *urllib* library, I don't get any response.

URL: https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full.csv (Reference Page: https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm)

What I tried:

```
import requests
eqfile = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full.csv')
```

got no respnse. Then tried the following

```
temp = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm')
```

again no response.

What would be the optimal way to download a file from such a URL (web server)?

Comment: server may check many elements to block scripts/block - ie. it can check header `User-Agent` with browser name. `requests` as user agent send `python ...` so it is easy to recognize scritp/bot.

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/download-files-with-python/

Comment: Try downloading this CSV on terminal using CURL `curl -vvv https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full.csv` - I believe this has something to do with SSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I use header `User-Agent` similar to header used by real web browser then I can download it.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full.csv'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
#print(r.content)

with open('sec_bhavdata_full.csv', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(r.content)
```

---

Portals often check this header to block requests or format HTML specially for your browser/device. But `requests` (and `urllib.request`) send `"python ..."`  in this header.

Many portals needs only `'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'` to send content but other may need full header `User-Agent` or even other headers like `Referrer`, `Accept`, `Accept-Encoding`, `Accept-Language`. You can see headers used by your browser on page https://httpbin.org/get

from real browser

Comment: That was my first guess as well and I tried to set header as `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}` - I get `'Connection aborted.', OSError("(60, 'ETIMEDOUT')")` with this header but interestingly it works with `{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}` - probably I faked too much details?