# Download with python requests asks captcha but browser does

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, urllib3, python-requests-html

My code is using a simple python request (or pandas, urllib3, and others) to download a xlsx file.
There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279624/python-urllib-requests-fails-to-download-file-but-browser-does) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59205601/how-to-download-a-file-using-web-url-in-python-download-through-browser-works-b) but the answers do not apply.

I run this code:

```
import requests
headers= {}
headers['User-Agent']=  "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
bts = BytesIO(r.content)
```

And the r.content is an html with the following message

```
We apologize for the inconvenience...\n            ...but your activity and behavior on this site made us think that you are a bot.\n            Note: A number of things could be going on here.\n            \n                If you are attempting to access this site using an anonymous Private/Proxy network, please disable that and try accessing site again.\n                Due to previously detected malicious behavior which originated from the network you\'re using, please request unblock to site.\n
```

It seems the website is able to find out this is not a browser. I naturally do not want to solve captchas and am just thinking of masking the code as if it were my browser. Is it possible and how? Does the inspect option of this url give any solution?

My best attempts have downloaded corrupted files with a size between 1 and 3KB instead of the actual 800kb file.

Comment: Sounds like you'd have to use a browser automation tool like Selenium; looked into that yet?

Comment: use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser

Comment: servers may check many elements to detect bot - i.e. check different headers, check cookies, run JavaScript (and get information about browser like window size, installed extension, etc.), check time between requests (human can't run many requests in few milliseconds)